# Publish a custom post type from front

Tags: php, wordpress, frontend, custom-post-type

I want to publish a custom post type 'question' from the front-end, but when I submit the form I keep getting 404 error. Bellow is the form and form processing. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?
/**
 * Questions processing
 */
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] )) {

    // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
    if (isset ($_POST['title'])) {
        $title =  $_POST['title'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please add a question';
    }
    if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
        $description = $_POST['description'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please add a description';
    }

    // Add the content of the form to $post as an array
    $post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $description,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',           
        'post_type' => 'question'                 
    );
    wp_insert_post($post);  // Pass  the value of $post to WordPress the insert function


} // end IF

// Do the wp_insert_post action to insert it
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post'); 

?>




<h1>Add a question:</h1>

<!-- New Question Form -->

<div>

<form name="new_post" method="post" action="">

<p><label for="title">Question:</label><br />

<input type="text" value="" name="title" />

</p>

<p><label for="description">Details</label><br />

<textarea name="description" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea>

</p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Ask!" name="submit" /></p>

<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="question" />

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_post" />

<?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>

</form>

</div>

<!--// New Question Form -->
```

Comment: Maybe try and place your `do_action()` call just after `wp_insert_post($post)`.

Comment: your validation steps don't stop the script from saving the new post. is that what you want? if you don't have title or description in $_POST you will have two undefined variables ($title and $description) and you will try to save a new post with them

Comment: what do you see if you replace wp_insert_post($post); with $return = wp_insert_post($post); var_dump($return);

Comment: I will work on validation later, thanks for the tips. Now I just want to save the post.

Comment: i can't see the var_dump because when i click the submit button i get the 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need the add_action bit and I have a feeling is the $post variable itself that's causing issues.

```
/**
 * Questions processing
 */
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] )) {

    // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
    if (isset ($_POST['title'])) {
        $title =  $_POST['title'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please add a question';
    }
    if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
        $description = $_POST['description'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please add a description';
    }

    // Add the content of the form to $post as an array
    $new_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $description,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',           
        'post_type' => 'question'                 
    );
    $id = wp_insert_post($new_post);  // Pass  the value of $post to WordPress the insert function
    //Returns ID of the new post you just created
```

And just in case, also add a URL to your form tag:

```
<form name="new_post" method="post" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out:

I've deleted the line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="question" />
```

I think Wordpress is using somehow a post variable with this name and it get's an error if I use it on my own.